# Is 'distinctives' an obsolete word?

Tags: word-usage

Elsewhere on Stack Exchange I noticed the word 'distinctive' used as a noun and its plural expressed :

> How can we educate new users about our site distinctives ?

[Bible Hermeneutics - Meta](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803)

The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/55677?redirectedFrom=distinctive#eid) states that the word 'distinctive' is both an adjective and a noun but it lists references to the noun only up to the nineteenth century.

I can see that the word has a different meaning to 'characteristics' in that 'distinctives' refers to particular characteristics which distinguish something from others of its type.

So, a word which may be useful and a word which someone has used in living memory but is it, officially, an obsolete word ?

Comment: If "Incredibles" isn't obsolete, why would "distinctives" be?

Comment: @HotLicks The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/94046?redirectedFrom=incredible#eid) has a solitary reference for the noun 'incredible' from 1610. And, indeed, the OED specifies that it is normally in the plural form. But you are quite correct, it does not tell me that the word is obsolete.

Comment: Note that there are a number of other words (eg, "notables") where an adjective has been nounified and then pluralized.  Though there are no doubt informal "rules" for when this is allowed, it is a reasonably legitimate action, and the resulting word is likewise "legitimate" even if rare or even "one-off'.

Comment: Even the nounal definition of "distinctive" is obsolete, it remains commonplace to use adjectives as nouns that stand for what that noun describes.  In fact, it's a known literary device whose name excapes me right now.  It's what Hillary Clinton did when she quite famously (or infamously, depending on your politics) referred to half of Trump supporters as a "basket of *deplorables*."

Comment: @BenjaminHarman I would argue that the nounal definition [isn't obsolete.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22distinctives%22&safe=active&ssui=on) (2000, 2003, 2005, 2007, 2011 [+ more]).  See my answer for further info.  Regarding the fact that dictionaries do not list the plural, not everything can be found on the Internet.

Comment: I just remembered.  The literary device, or rhetorical technique, is called "synecdoche."  It's where you refer to an object using another noun or adjective, that noun or adjective being something outstanding or deviant in the object and so is being used to represent the whole (e.g., "There are 26 heads" to mean "There are 26 students" and "The foolish do not suffer for being so but it is the rest of us who do" using "foolish" to mean people who are foolish).

Comment: @Lordology -- I totally agree.  My keyboard delays sometimes and it throws off my typing.  What I meant to say is "Even *if* the nounal..."  I didn't intend to argue that "distinctive" is obsolete, instead leaving that argument on the table because it is immaterial since it's standard fare to use adjectives as nouns, there even being a word for doing that: synedoche.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman  OK, thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: if it were the obsolete the OED would note it as such that the usages examples stop before our era usually mean that the entry for the word has not been updated in a while.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR of my post: It hasn't fallen out of use enough/doesn't fit the criteria for obsoleteness, and the plural noun form is still used today.

---

#### No.

But before we can proceed, we must look at [what makes a word obsolete.](https://qz.com/1061782/the-complex-process-that-dictionaries-use-to-decide-which-words-are-obsolete/)

> “We rarely take words out of our dictionaries,” says Mary O’Neill, managing editor of the largest single-volume English language dictionary, the unabridged Collins English Dictionary, which clocks in at 2,305 pages. “This is especially true of our larger dictionaries. **If we find that a word has fallen out of general use, or is not used as much as it was before,** we usually label such words as ‘obsolete,’ ‘archaic,’ or ‘old-fashioned’ rather than deleting them entirely.”

This paragraph, from Mary O'Neill of the CED, tells us that words **that have fallen out of general use** have the possibility of being marked obsolete.

But does *distinctive(s)* match this criterion?

Well, [on the OED page](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/55677?redirectedFrom=distinctive#eid), it's marked as a **Band 6 word, though this is probably for the adjectival form, is:**

> Band 6 contains words which occur between 10 and 100 times per million words in typical modern English usage, including a wide range of descriptive vocabulary. It contains many nouns referring to specific objects, entities, processes, and ideas, **running from dog, horse, ship, machine, mile, assessment, army, career, stress to gas, explosion, desert, parish, envelope, and headache...**

So this implies that it's a word used as much as *desert*, to name one.

If we head over to [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=distinctives&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=8&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdistinctives%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdistinctives%3B%2Cc0), the word, including the noun form, appears to be on the up!

But if we head over to [pretty much all dictionaries](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distinctive#other-words), [even Google's](https://www.google.com/search?q=distinctives%20meaning&rlz=1CAXWWL_enGB813GB813&oq=distinctives%20meaning&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0.3676j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on), it doesn't appear to be a word.

**However**, as *distinctives* **is** the understandable plural of *distinctive*, **lexicographers won't remove words that can be drawn from other words.**

From Peter Gilliver, Senior Editor of the OED:

> “Because a word like *livery* is still current, we don’t mark the extremely scarce derivative *liveryless* as obsolete because it is formed from elements which are still current and could be re-formed at any time.”

#### This applies to *distinctives*. (*distinctive* + -s plural)

[Here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=faTHAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT1&dq=%22distinctives%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8sKeEiazhAhWkSRUIHRBuCT0Q6AEIOjAD#v=onepage&q=%22distinctives%22&f=false) is a book example *from 2007* where it's used as a noun.  [There are more examples](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22distinctives%22&safe=active&ssui=on), should you care to look.

Since *distinctive* [as a noun is still a used word today (See NGrams again); not marked as rare or otherwise](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/distinctive), we can draw the conclusion:

### There is no evidence to support it being rare; as a noun, it is still used today; therefore it is not, by most standards, an obsolete word.

Comment: If the downvoter could briefly explain why they did what they did, that would be great.

Comment: I think you may be getting down votes because you said "TL;DR."  What the asker wrote wasn't very long, and saying you didn't bother to read it, well, that's a bit rough, a rude thing to say.  You can get away with saying things like that on Twitter or Yahoo Answers, but this site doesn't put up with it.  This site has a culture wherein there's a standard of respect, and telling someone you're answering that you didn't even bother to read what they wrote because it was too long, especially when it wasn't, is beyond the pale for this site.

Comment: @Lordology -- Easy with the explanation points.  You asked a question and I'm just spit-balling.  I didn't give you a down vote.  Anyway, when you say "TL;DR," it doesn't come across as being about your answer, not to me.  So, I'm just making a *friendly* suggestion based on my humble opinion.  That's all.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Apologies for the exclamation marks.  I was just panicked about offending someone/people; I thought **I** was being helpful by summarising my answer.

Comment: @Lordology --  No worries.  I see you deleted the "TL;DR."  Maybe you'll see a turn around.  People on this site tend to come back and revise their votes when they see something they didn't like or didn't agree with has been edited or removed.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Not to worry, I have rollbacked my edit with an apology and rephrased summary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91782/discussion-between-lordology-and-benjamin-harman).

Comment: @BenjaminHarman That’s not what _tl;dr_ means when written in an answer like this. It does stand for ‘too long; didn’t read’ and was originally used on forums to say that someone else’s post was too long so you couldn’t be arsed reading it; but in an answer like this, it means “here’s the short version, in case the whole thing is too long for you to be arsed reading it” – i.e., not a rude “I didn’t bother reading your post” but a self-deprecating “you probably won’t bother reading mine”. It is quite common in long answers here to put a tl;dr at the beginning or end.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet So... I should've just kept it.

Comment: @Lordology There’s no harm in changing it for “Summary” or similar – after all, not everyone knows what _tl;dr_ means at all – but I wouldn’t say there’s anything wrong with leaving it in either.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet So this takes us back to the first question:  why the downvotes?

Comment: @Lordology I didn’t downvote, so I don’t know what reasons the downvoters had; random downvotes are common enough here. I don’t have access to the OED from my phone where I am now, but I do wonder about the band 6 ‘rating’ in the OED – is that not including the adjective? It seems inconceivable to me that the noun should be band 6 by itself, since it is very rare (cf. Ngrams – many decimals!). It’s worth noting that all the Google Books examples appear to be the theological sense; it seems to enjoy some religious-academic use, but beyond that, I’ve never heard or seen it used.

Comment: (The fact that it seems to be an almost entirely academic word also fits in with the surge in usage since around the 1950s, since that’s around the time academic articles and books starting really exploding in numbers. The overall frequency is still very low, though. If you compare with the plural of another band 6 word, like _assessments_, you’ll see that _distinctives_ is dwarfed completely – _assessments_ appears more than 1,500 times as frequently.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I've edited to clarify.  However, how did you make the 1,500 statement (I don't doubt it, I'm just interested).

Comment: @Lordology If you Ngram _assessments_, it’s somewhere around 0.000900%, where _distinctives_ is around 0.000006%, which is a ratio of 1,500 (unless I miscalculated in my head – my brain gets frazzled with all those zeros).